# NullPointerException, Trying to add JPanel Array to Container

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe, jlabel

Can't figure out why I am getting this exception, Console returns this message:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
JFrame b = new JFrame("Lotus");
Container pieces = new Container();
JLabel[] labelsP1 = new JLabel[10];
JLabel[] labelsP2 = new JLabel[10];

for(int i = 0 ; i < labelsP1.length ; i++){
    labelsP1[i] = new JLabel(B1); 
    for(int j = 0 ; j < labelsP2.length ; j++){
        labelsP2[j] = new JLabel(B2); 
    }
    for (JLabel label : labelsP1) {
        pieces.add(label);
    }

    Container c = b.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(13,3)); 
    c.add(pieces);
}
```

Comment: I've reformatted your code - it would be *really* helpful if you could format your code nicely when posting questions in future. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. Also, you haven't told us anything about `pieces`.

Comment: Where is declaration of `pieces` variable?

Comment: I guess `pieces` is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your 3rd inner loop is iterating throw a null array

```
 for (JLabel label : labelsP1) {
        pieces.add(label);
    }
```

//

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < labelsP1.length ; i++)
{
    labelsP1[i] = new JLabel(B1); 
    for(int j = 0 ; j < labelsP2.length ; j++)
    {
        labelsP2[j] = new JLabel(B2); 
    }
    for (JLabel label : labelsP1)   // null only labelsP1[0] is initialized
    {
        pieces.add(label);        
    }

    Container c = b.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(13,3)); 
    c.add(pieces);
}
```

Comment: As labelsP1 is filled upto i. Also the nesting of `for i` and `for j` suggests one `new JLabel[]` should happen inside the first `for i`.

Comment: check Deadron comment, it looks like your code is missing a bracket.

Answer (score 2):

For starters it does not look like you are showing us all the code which things difficult.
Secondly, is it the intent that your first for loop is containing all of the code after it? It seems likely you have a bracket misplacement issue.  I would guess you need a closing brace.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < labelsP1.length ; i++){
        labelsP1[i] = new JLabel(B1); 
        for(int j = 0 ; j < labelsP2.length ; j++){
            labelsP2[j] = new JLabel(B2); 
    }
```

to

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < labelsP1.length ; i++) {
    labelsP1[i] = new JLabel(B1);
}

for(int j = 0 ; j < labelsP2.length ; j++) {
    labelsP2[j] = new JLabel(B2); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In thie code below :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < labelsP1.length ; i++){
labelsP1[i] = new JLabel(B1); 
for(int j = 0 ; j < labelsP2.length ; j++){
    labelsP2[j] = new JLabel(B2); 
}
for (JLabel label : labelsP1) {
    pieces.add(label);
}
```

You are adding **JLabels** to the array **labelsP1** one by one and also iterating over the array. But you are trying to access all the elements from it which does not exist.

I would suggest you to remove nested for loops to get proper behaviour and avoid NullPointerException.